# Gzip Content encoding error on some pages in php

Tags: php, apache, compression

I am using Gzip compression method in php.
Intially, it works fine on my site as soon as I login in I get Content encoding error.

I know that we get this type of error in FF when there is some error in PHP but I checked that too and there is no error in my php code.

So, why it is giving error on this page in particular ?

Thanks

Comment: What's the exact error? Some code would probably be useful too.

Comment: Firefox stops the rendering and says "Content Encoding Error"..check this link http://blog.absolutedisaster.co.uk/php-compression-with-gzip-content-encoding-er  I followed this but still I am getting error